# "TypeError: 'Model' object is not callable" when trying to build a basic model using pymc3

Tags: python, pymc3

I'm having trouble getting a basic example using the pymc3 package to run.  the example comes from [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/markov-chain-monte-carlo-in-python-44f7e609be98) tutorial on building Markov Chain Monte Carlo models using python.

When I get to any loop that attempts to build a model, I get an error that reads:  TypeError: 'Model' object is not callable.

Here is an example:

```
import pymc3 as pm
with pm.Model() as model:
    x = pm.Data('x', [1., 2., 3.])
    y = pm.Data('y', [1., 2., 3.])
    beta = pm.Normal('beta', 0, 1)
    obs = pm.Normal('obs', x * beta, 1, observed=y)
    trace = pm.sample(1000, tune=1000)
```

I'm using Python version 3.7 and the most current version of pymc3 (and all dependencies).  I realize that this is a really basic error and I appreciate any help anybody can offer.

Here is the complete stack trace of the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\Lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2961, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-76-847c37ac79c2>", line 2, in <module>
    with pm.Model() as model:
TypeError: 'Model' object is not callable
```

Comment: Looks like you're doing `model()` somewhere in your code

Comment: What's the error with trace?

Comment: I thought the same thing about model(), but I checked and I'm not.  This is the first time the word 'model' appears anywhere, and the error is specifically referencing the capital 'M' Model.

Comment: Agree this code *should* work. I would check that `pymc3` is the pip installed module (try adding `print(pm)` just before the error, and it should point to a file in a directory called `site_packages`), or that somehow `pm.Model` got overwritten (which seems like a longshot)